# Requests in firefox were not send

Tags: javascript, cors, firefox-addon, preflight

I'm trying to port my Chrome-Plugin to firefox as an addon.
My addon fires requests, which are working completely fine in chrome, but in firefox, they were not fired. 
Even in the network-tab, I cant see them. 
I did some research and find out that it could have something to do with "preflight" requests. So I think my original request gets blocked by the preflight request. Its also a cors-request.
How can I fix this problem? In chrome it just works fine, I didn't do anything to make explicit a cors-request.
I tried to add crossDomain: true, to the request-constructor, but it didn't help.
This is my request:

```
var searchReq = $.get(
        "https://www.corsdomain.com/search",
        {
            q: $searchfield.val(),
            maxResults: 20,
            crossDomain:true
        },
        function (response) {
            processResponse(response);
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is a problem with the file(s) that store the extensions registry.

Delete the extensions.* files (e.g. extensions.sqlite, extensions.ini) and compatibibility.ini in the Firefox profile folder to reset the extensions registry.

https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Profiles
New files will be created when required.

See "Corrupt extension files":

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Unable_to_install_themes_or_extensions
https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Unable+to+install+add-ons
If you see disabled or not compatible extensions in "Firefox/Tools > Add-ons > Extensions" then click the Tools button at the left end of the Search Bar to check if there is a compatibibility update available.

If this hasn't helped then also delete the addons.sqlite file.

You can also check for problems caused by a corrupted localstore.rdf file.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Corrupt_localstore.rdf
https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Troubleshooting+extensions+and+themes

Comment: I only have 2 files: extensions.json and addons.json. Deleted both, but it didn't help. I'm using already firefox developer edition